# calculating percentage using data not in the scope of row group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I need to calculate percentage in SSRS based on row data belonging to different group.

The row where percentage is calculated is not in the scope of row group.

```
=(971/(971+480+215))*100
```

The value 480 and 215 are from RowGroup1 and RowGroup2 respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Last()? Whatever formula would calculate 480 and 215 in RowGroup1 and RowGroup2, enclose that formula in Last() and give it the context of those groups, so...

```
=(971/(971+Last(<<formula>>, "RowGroup1")+Last(<<formula>>, "RowGroup2"))) * 100
```

I think that should do it - it's basically just getting data as if it were the last row in the specified group which (and I'm assuming you're using some aggregation in those rowgroups) should be the 'total' you're looking to draw into this formula.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in SQL like this:

```
SELECT
data/SUM(data) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)*100  AS Perentage
```